# Suddenly XP computer is randomly hibernating or shutting down when Firefox is up

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, crash

3.6.1.6 FireFox.

This has happened over the last couple of days. If I don't boot Firefox, everything seems okay. But when I boot Firefox these random things happen.

Either the computer just shuts down, or it goes to hibernate.

All power saving settings are set so this will not happen.

If it shuts down, it just does that.
If it hibernates, if I restart it fairly immediately, the computer then works normally for a couple of hours, then shuts down. If I don't restart it from hibernation fairly quickly, it just shuts down.

Any clues?

Comment: If you uninstall/reinstall Firefox, does the same behavior happen?

Comment: You can probably have a virus in you OS. This may be some bad firefox plugin or firefox is infected. Try to scan you computer.

Comment: I have scanned my computer a few times with MSE and Malwarebytes - nothing. Full scan.

Comment: @Chris - I have just downloaded and installed FF 4. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing the latest version of Firefox (4) here:

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/

If the problem still persists then it is most likely a corrupt profile.

As you are using Windows XP you will need to do the following:

Go to RUN.. and enter:

```
"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\"
```

Click OK and you will come to a folder showing "Extensions " & "Firefox"

Go to Firefox and then Profiles.

You will see a folder that has some random characters followed by .default, e.g. tpjd9gsu.default

Simply just rename the folder to something like tpjd9gsu.default.backup -- notice I just added .backup to the end.

This way firefox will not load all your settings and act as if it was a new installation.

If the problem persists then it could be an issue with your Operating System.

Comment: I upgraded to FF 4. The problem seems gone. THanks.